# hide div after YouTube video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I am working on a simple one page website for a friend, which contains a YouTube video embed. I'm not very familiar with the YouTube API, but I got the follow to work (see below). What do I need to change so that when the video completes the player disappears and a DIV is loaded.

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'y-y8v4BClZE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 720000);
        done = true;
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script works, you should just do :

```
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
    document.getElementById("player").style.display = "none";
}
```

As for the detection of the end of the video, you should do :

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {          
        stopVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Agree with those sentiments, in that function you can do what you need.

Comment: is `stopVideo` when the video ends or is it when its paused?

Comment: By looking at `function onPlayerStateChange` it's when the video ends (fixed time of 720000 ms)

Comment: I will try this - just curious I only set the fixed time of 720000 ms, since I could not figure out how to not have the video auto pause after 6 seconds. Is there a way to just have the video play start to finish without setting a fixed time?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help - so far everything works - http://www.soledad.matthewgideon.com/youtube.html - I do have one last question.. For some reason just before the video closes - there is a quick image that flashes up, not really sure why.

Comment: @user3096500 I don't see it my browser goes too fast ^^ maybe try to invert the "display none" and "stopVideo" lines in the stopVideo function